# Firebase Error signing in anonymously: (auth/network-request-failed)

Tags: javascript, typescript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm attempting to sign in anonymously on my react TypeScript project and getting an auth error.

My firebase version is up to date and I have the Anonymous provider enabled on the console's Authentication, with 127.0.0.1 and localhost both set as authorized domains. The firebase initialization and authentication has been completed by the time get to the relevant portion.

Would gladly add any info you might find helpful.
Appreciate any help!

Code sample:

```
signInAnonymously(auth).then(cred => {
  console.log(cred);
})
```

Error:

> OrderHandler.ts:29 Error signing in anonymously: FirebaseError: Firebase: Error (auth/network-request-failed).

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.